# Passing in values to scripts running under PHP built-in server

Tags: php, sqlite, phpunit

I have a PHP application which implements an API as a RESTful web service and uses SQLite for data storage. The relevant software versions are:

- PHP: PHP 5.4.30 (cli) (built: Jul 29 2014 23:43:29)
- SQLite: 3.7.13
- PHPUnit: 4.3.4

I'm using PHPUnit to test the application in two broad areas:

1. Testing the methods of each class.
2. Testing the web service URLs (e.g. that `GET /items/1` returns a JSON representation of item 1).

Testing the methods of each class is easy as everything is handled within PHPUnit and I can set constants to given values using a `phpunit.xml` configuration file (including the path to the test database which is created at the start of the test run and the data is reset for each test). For testing the web service I have a bootstrap script which starts up the PHP built-in server like so:

`php -S localhost:8000 -t ./htdocs`

The bootstrap script also stores the ID of the server process so it can kill it when PHPUnit finishes. This all works as I'd expect.

The problem I'm having is that when I'm testing the web service, I want it to use the test database, in production I want it to use the live database, and the two databases have different paths. At present the production database path is defined by a constant in a `config.php` file, but I want to override that when running PHPUnit. Ideally I'd like to pass in a value via the built-in server using something like the following:

`php -S localhost:8000 -t ./htdocs -D DATABASE_PATH=/path/to/sqlite.db`

Where `DATABASE_PATH` would appear as a constant in the PHP code which runs the web service. I can then use an `if (!defined('DATABASE_PATH')` check to provide the live database path if no path has already been specified. Is there a way to do this using the built-in server? I've checked the man page for `php` but I can find any arguments which provide this functionality - the closest I've found is `-d` for defining INI entries.

Alternatively, am I going about this the wrong way and is there another (better?) way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

you can call:

```
$ php -S localhost:8000 router.php
```

where `router.php` is your dispatcher file like (copied from documentation page):

```
<?php
// router.php
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli-server') {
    /* route static assets and return false */
}
/* go on with normal index.php operations */
?>
```

so once you detected `cli-server` you can

`define('PHPUNIT_DATABASE_PATH','path/to/your/database';`

did you try that?

Comment: That does work, although it feels a bit clunky as I've now got the test database path defined in two different places.

Comment: you can just put this `if` condition directly to your original settings file, and don't use router.php at all

Comment: That's not quite the same thing though - I only want this value to be set when I'm running unit tests, adding the if block to my config file would mean that the test would be made on every `require 'config.php'` call in production. Also, placing it in my config file would still mean I had two places defining the constant (`config.php` and `phpunit.xml`).

Comment: No, if you put condition `if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli-server') {` to the file where you set up database connection. that would set one database when `'cli-server'` and another one or the same one for `else` it is not require NEW php file, it is require just to add this condition to any or many files where you want to check if your environment is testing environment. I don't suggest you to define constant, that was your will in your question.you can do whatever you want  when `if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli-server') {` it is just condition(trigger) to see who called the app, real user or test unit